# setBackgroundResource in onItemCheckStateChanged doesn't work for the first selection

Tags: android, listview, multichoiceitems

I am working on an android project where I have a grid view and I am setting it up with a MultiChoiceModeListener.

When I long click, it successfully creates the contextual action bar but setting the `setBackgroundResource` on the initial item that creates the CAB doesn't have any affect, however all subsequent items that are selected, the background resource is successfully applied. Below is the code I am using:

```
gridView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        gridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
            {
                Log.d("DirectoryPicker-CAB", "CheckedStateChanged");
                //findViewById((int)gridView.getItemIdAtPosition(position)).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DirectoryPicker.this, R.color.appPrimaryColour));
                //Toast.makeText(DirectoryPicker.this, "Item CAB Clicked: Checked: " + (checked ? "true" : "false"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(DirectoryPicker.this, "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (checked)
                {

                    //gridView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DirectoryPicker.this, R.color.appPrimaryColour));
                    Log.d("DirectoryPicker-View", gridView.getChildAt(position).toString());
                    gridView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.appPrimaryColour);
                    mode.invalidate();


                    directoryAdapter.getItem(position).setSelected(true);
                    selectedDirectories.add(directoryAdapter.getItem(position));

                }
                else
                {
                    directoryAdapter.getItem(position).setSelected(false);
                    FileManager.DirectoryOrFileInfo selectedDirectory = directoryAdapter.getItem(position);
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedDirectories.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (selectedDirectories.get(i) == selectedDirectory)
                        {
                            selectedDirectories.remove(i);
                            selectedDirectory.setSelected(false);
                        }
                    }
                    gridView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(DirectoryPicker.this, android.R.color.transparent));
                }
                mode.setTitle(selectedDirectories.size() + " selected");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
            {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.file_dir_cab_menu, menu);
                Log.d("DirectoryPicker-CAB", "OnActionModeCreate");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
            {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
            {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
            {
                selectedDirectories.clear();
            }
        });
```

Why does the background resource not get successfully applied for the first item that is long clicked that creates the CAB, but it works fine for all subsequent selections.

Comment: There is code snippet in the [guide to context menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#CAB), there they start the Action Mode *and* call `view.setSelected(true);` - maybe that's what you're missing

Comment: I'll give that a try thanks, I have that but its on the adapter not the view. If that is the case though, surprised it works on the subsequent selected items.

Comment: I've given it a try but unfortunately doesn't seem to make any difference :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured why this isn't working now. When the CAB is created, it triggers the `getView` function to be called again in my adapter so it ends up resetting the view back to how it was again.

I've therefore changed my adapter instead in the `getView` method so it checks whether the item is marked as checked, and it sets the background resource.